# How to open a GE Hotpoint HTW200 washer?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I'm attempting to disassemble a GE Hotpoint washer *(model# htw200ask2ww)* in order to check (and likely replace) the suspension rod.

Every video, guide, and manual online says that to open all top-loading GE washers, you remove the front-panel and unlatch the lid using a putty knife.  However, this washer doesn't have a front-panel, and there don't seem to be any latches!

[image: washer]

*(I shoved a putty knife under the lid every which way, with no luck)*

How the hell do you open this thing?

Comment: Could you post more pictures please? This is surely something none of us are seeing.

Comment: The control panel on the rear, give us a photo of the backside. there is probably screws that hold the panel on the top, via the rear. Once removed, the panel will disconnect. you will likely expose more screws under it for the top cover. If this is not the case, lets see the bottom/back rear.

Comment: Looks like you'd use a putty knife to release [part 328, "washing machine clip spring cover"](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/ModelSectionParts/HTW200ASK2WW/4/0/0/0/CABINET), which should allow the [top panel and lid](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/ModelSectionParts/HTW200ASK2WW/2/0/0/0/TOP_PANEL_&_LID) to lift up and away yielding cabinet access. (There may be filters passing through top panel and lid into cabinet that need to be removed, possibly also screws on their housing assemblies.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what part you're referring to replacing, but PartSelect has diagrams of all the component parts (and sells some of them). If you need to get completely into the cabinet, it doesn't look like there's a panel to remove & may need to be accessed from above. It appears the top panel is held in place by spring clips (328) and a couple screws (570)? But it looks like you may have to take off the controls to get to those screws.

I'm not an appliance repair technician, so take my ideas as you would any other from a stranger on the internet.

[HTW200ASK2WW General Electric Washer - Overview](https://www.partselect.com/Models/HTW200ASK2WW/)